# Android Studio cannot resolve androidx symbols

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

Recently migrated to androidx but when I open the project in Android Studio the symbols for androidx libraries are all red and cannot be resolved.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Open the project in Android studio:

```
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart
```

This fixed it and the imports all resolved correctly.